# SqlException Cannot open database The login failed To execute the procedure

Tags: c#

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=SSPI; database= Students" providerName="System.Data.sqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>



    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procedureGetStudentByID", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                //Class Student 
                Student student = new Student();
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I have a procedure to execute with name `procedureGetStudentByID`, but when I run the web service to test the method it displays this message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "Students" requested by the login. The login failed.

Comment: "The login failed" seems pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

"The login failed" seems pretty self explanatory.

Given this is integrated security (SSPI), if you're actually running this in a web service you need to consider what user account in responsible for that service. It's almost certainly not your own user account, which is why it might seem to work if you test things within Visual Studio. Then you need to make sure this user account has permission to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

either name of your db is not students or you cant login true integrated security

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this connectionString settings? Instead of Database use Initial Catalog

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=Students" providerName="System.Data.sqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I get the same result unfortunately